# Python - ANSI Terminal Colors w/o Enabled in Registry

Tags: python, windows

Using ANSI Escape Sequences we can give terminals a nice vibrant color, however for Windows this much be enabled via **Registry.**

There is a module named [Colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) which works even if terminal colors are disabled. I've looked through the source and I'm unable to find how it works.

I could set the registry key but 1. That would require elevation and 2. That would require the console to be restarted to work. Is there any way to avoid this how Colorama has?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs, it is listed that it doesnt actually use ANSI escape sequences, but insteads converts them on the fly to Win32 calls:

`On Windows, calling init() will filter ANSI escape sequences out of any text sent to stdout or stderr, and replace them with equivalent Win32 calls.`

Here is the Win documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN

The above syscall does not require elevation nor a registry key. So Colorama is essentially a clever interpreter/converter.

Comment: Thank you! So I would get a handle to STDOUT and use the SetConsoleTextAttribute function to set the color? Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, and luckily python has a submodule for that too which doesn't require elevation either! If you liked my answer, please press the checkmark to mark it as "accepted". Thank you!

Comment: Oh and just to add to this, Windows is moving away from this and instead slowly replacing the "CMD" with "Terminal" which has color and emoji support built-in.

Comment: Awesome! So terminals will switch to UTF-8 rather than ANSI? Awesome :) - I accepted your post, thanks a million for your help!

Comment: Yep, and you can get it right now already if you have Win10 or newer. It's on the Windows Store and Github and just called "Terminal" (and its awesome)